# How do I display first name and first initial of last name in PHP

Tags: php

I need to be able to show the first name and the first initial of the last name.

`Mike Jones = Mike. J.`

This is what I've done so far:

```php
function abbreviateName($whole_name)
{
    $alterName = str_word_count($whole_name);
    
    if($alterName >= 2)
    {
        print_r (explode(" ", $whole_name, 2));
        // echo "\n$whole_name";
        echo chop($whole_name);
        
    return $whole_name;
    }
}

$name = 'Mike Jones';

abbreviateName($name);
```

My output as is:

```php
Array
(
    [0] => Mike
    [1] => Jones
)
Mike Jones
```

***MY QUESTION***

I've used the chop function in multiple ways but nothing works. From what I know in JavaScript, if I wanted to do this, I would refer to $whole_name on line 10 as `$whole_name[1][1]` to reference the first initial of the last name.

Why does that not work in PHP?

Comment: For a general and safer solution, you should make sure you get the names separated in firstname/lastname (two different variables) since some people have double first names and/or last names (and not everyone are using hyphens).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `mb_substr` along with `reset` and `end` methods

```
function abbreviateName($whole_name)
{
    $alterName = str_word_count($whole_name);
    
    if($alterName >= 2)
    {
      $nameExploded = explode(' ',$whole_name);
      
      $firstName = reset($nameExploded);
      $lastName = mb_substr(end($nameExploded), 0, 1);
        
        return $firstName.'. '.$lastName.'.';
    }
  return $whole_name;
}

$nameOne = 'Mike Jones';
$nameTwo = 'First Middle Last';
$nameThree = 'First Middle Two End';
$nameFour = "John";

abbreviateName($nameOne);//will output Mike. J.
abbreviateName($nameTwo);//will output First. L.
abbreviateName($nameThree);//will output First. E.
abbreviateName($nameFour);//will output John
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode and customize the first 2 element.

```
function abbreviateName($whole_name) {

  if($whole_name == "")
    return "";

  $tmp = explode(" ", $whole_name, 2)
  if(count($tmp)<=1) {
    return ucwords($tmp[0]).".";
  } else {
    $fn = ucwords($tmp[0]);
    $ln = ucwords(substr($tmp[1],0,1);
    return $fn.". ".$ln.".";
  }

}
```

Side Note: PHP chop() Remove characters from the right end of a string, example below, this will give Hello as result.

```
chop("Hello World!","World!");
```